# Meaning of expression "What you say is not congruent"

Tags: meaning, expressions

From what I can google up, congruency can have different meanings? Is this as response in a dicussion to say "I do not believe you?"

Comment: What's said does not fit the facts under discussion.

Answer (score 2):

super simple

it means

what you say does not follow the pattern of reason or rhyme beforehand.

Comment: like, "what you tell is nonsense/bs" or "changed your mind illogicaly"?

Comment: Exactly. "What you say is not congruent" means "what you present lacks internal consistency."

Answer (score 1):

"[congruent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/congruent)" means "In agreement" or "in harmony" and can only really be applied to two or more things.

So, unless "you" refers to two or more people, this sentence, *“What you say is not congruent”* doesn't really make sense.  It sounds like an example of **[magniloquence](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/magniloquence)** - using unnecessarily "flowery" or complicated language.  In other words, I think the speaker is somewhere on a spectrum between pretentious and simply wrong.

Comment: It definitely sounds cryptic. I would be tempted to answer "Congruent with what?"

Comment: What "is said" by one person might be several statements. These statements might not be congruent with each other.

Comment: @Davo if that is the case, then "What you say is not congruent" is still a poor way to express the sentiment.  "Your statements are not congruent" would at least be formally correct, but it's still clunky.